# Move XML Files based on Content

Tags: xml, powershell

I've got a bunch of XML files that need to be moved to different folders based on their content (rentity_id).

The following code simply checks the content of one of the XML files and moves all of them based on that one, which clearly is not what I intended.

```
$dir = 'H:\New_folder\TEST_DATA'
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter *xml | Foreach-Object {
$rentity_id = Select-Xml -Xpath '//rentity_id' -Path $_.FullName  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If($rentity_ID.node.innertext -eq "727"){
Move-Item "H:\New_folder\TEST_DATA\*.xml" "H:\New_folder\WUPSIL\" -Force
}
Else{
Move-Item "H:\New_folder\TEST_DATA\.*xml" "H:\New_folder\WUIB\" -Force
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sourceDirectory = "C:\temp\source"
$destinationDirectoryRoot = "C:\temp\destination"

# Grab a list of XML source files
$xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDirectory -Filter "*.xml"

# Iterate over the files
foreach ($xmlFile in $xmlFiles) {
    # Grab the content and cast to [xml] type
    [xml]$xmlContent = Get-Content -Path $xmlFile.FullName

    # We now don't need to use [icky] XPath 
    $rentityId = $xmlContent.rentity_id

    # Do work if we found a value for rentity_id
    if ($rentityId) {
        # Variables for destination dir and file
        $destinationDirectory = Join-Path -Path $destinationDirectoryRoot -ChildPath $rentityId
        $destinationFile = Join-Path -Path $destinationDirectory -ChildPath $xmlFile.Name

        # Create destination folder (same name as XML file)
        New-Item -Path $destinationDirectory -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null

        # Move the source file to thenewly created destination directory
        Move-Item -Path $xmlFile.FullName -Destination $destinationFile -Force
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "No rentity_id found in $($xmlFile.FullName)"
    }
}

# Confirm output
Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationDirectoryRoot -Filter "*.xml" -Recurse |
    Select-Object FullName
```